# Uncaught SyntaxError: Export 'e' is not defined in module (at vite.js?v=d59cec13:236:3) - in three.js/vite combo

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

So I'm trying to get back to javascript and I noticed that three.js is kinda cool. After a few hours trying to set everything up it worked, but when I tried to make some geometry and render it it stopped working. when I try to check the error it shows me this:
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMJqX.png)

```json
{
  "name": "threemaybe",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^1.32.1",
    "vite": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.146.0"
  }
}
```

^package.json^

```js
import './style.css'

import * as THREE from 'three';
import { getDepOptimizationConfig } from 'vite';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.Camera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight , 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.querySelector('#bg'),
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

camera.position.setZ(30);

renderer.render(scene,camera);


const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00F, wireframe:true});
const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);

scene.add(torus);

renderer.render(scane,camera);
```

^main.js^

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
    

  </body>
</html>
```

^index.html^

hope all of this is enough.

tried to draw a torus and I thought It would display the torus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleted this and it works now

```
import { getDepOptimizationConfig } from 'vite';
```